# Setup Magento 2 GA4 (Google Analytics 4) with GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

How to set up Magento 2 GA4 (Google Analytics 4) Ecommerce tracking with GTM?

I have already followed the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ecommerce-ga4#measure_productitem_list_viewsimpressions) but no success.

Comment: You should add as much details on the exact issues you encountered and show us that you've tried debugging it. That will help us help you.

Comment: @Cthulchu i have tray to  ecommerce tracking using GA4 property using give link but still it not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can completely understand that following the developer's documentation doesn't always work. However, using the same documentation I have successfully implemented GA4. Missing even one piece of information can render the setup incomplete. To help people such as yourself I have written a blog containing all the details related to the setup. You can check it out [here](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/how-to-setup-magento-2-ga4google-analytics-4.html).